# Tiling an image to fit on a one page printout

Tags: php, html, css, image, printing

Rather than having users print out a single image per page, I would like to save some paper. I'm trying to setup a printout that will tile an image as many times as it will fit on a single page.

Is it possible to know the dimensions being printed to and arrange the page accordingly? Or are there any tricks I can use?

Comment: To print several smaller pictures on one page, right-click the pictures you want, and then click Print. You'll see a preview of your picture in the Print Pictures dialog box. Depending on the number of pictures you're printing, you might use more than one sheet of paper. source ---  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/picture-printing-faq#1TC=windows-7

Comment: sorry but I am confused! how many image(s) you have in your page? also, providing a >> **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** << will be very helpful

Comment: Basically, it's a page with a single, user generated image. The user would then print out as many copies as they would like. In an effort to save paper, I would like to arrange the print page to tile the image as many times as possible on a single piece of paper.